# Identifying two random sequences in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that flips a coin and then outputs whether the result is heads (H) or tails (T):

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class coin {
        public static void main (String [] arg) {
            Random r = new Random(); 
            int flip = r.nextInt(2);
            if (flip == 1) {
                System.out.print("H");
            } else {
                System.out.print("T");
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, I would like the program to continue flipping the coin until it flips 3 heads in a row.

So for instances, I want it to output the following which stops after it identifies 3 heads:

H T T H T H T H H H

I'm having issues figuring out how to get Java to continue flipping the coins. I've tried implementing a for-loop which let me flip the coin a fixed amount of times, but I would rather that the program figures out how many times the coin is flip by itself. I suspect it should be with a while-loop but I can't seem to figure out how that would be implemented. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter to keep track of how many heads have been flipped and loop until 3 heads have been flipped:

```
Random r = new Random();
int counter = 0;
while(counter <3) 
{
    int flip = r.nextInt(2);
    if (flip == 1) {
        System.out.print("H");
        counter++;
    } else {
        System.out.print("T");
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You only forgot to reset counter.

Comment: @Antoniossss My mistake. Edited

Comment: All I can say is **THTTTTTHTHTTHHH**

Comment: Oh that's really smart. I have to be better at thinking like a programmer and coming up with workarounds like adding a counter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Somehing like this:

```
int headsInRow=0;
while(headsInRow<3){

  int flip=doFlip();
  if(heads)headsInRow++;
  else headsInRow=0;
}
```

ofc it is a pseudocode but you should get the idea.

Comment: That "headsInRow" was the missing link for me. My thoughts were more in the lines of identifying the string "H H H" but this makes much more sense. I definitely need more practice coming up with these solutions. Thank you!